Make table row span multiple pages
I'm trying to implement Word table behaviour with tabularray. I stuck with a cell containing long text, which should span several pages. But it moves row to next page and protrude into the bottom margin. My table is like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetTblrTemplate{middlehead, lasthead, foot, caption}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
{
    hlines,
    vlines,
    columns={halign=c, valign=m, co=1},
}
    Some column & Long text column & Some column \\
    simple text & \lipsum & simple text \\
    simple text & \lipsum & simple text \\
    simple text & \lipsum & simple text \\
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}


Page breaks inside a table cell are not supported. For two column tables using a list is often an option.

My actual table has 5 columns and 6 rows. If you didn't understand, it should break on rows.

You example table has only two table rows. The whole \lipsum is one table cell. And as I said: page breaks inside table cells are not supported. You need to break the \lipsum manually into several table cells (e.g. paragraph by paragraph). Then you would get more than one page.

In your original example, the table had only two table rows: One with the head and one with a \lipsum that produces several paragraphs inside a single table cell. Now it has four table rows: One with the head and three with two short texts and a \lipsum that produces several paragraphs inside a single table cell.
Page breaks inside table cells are not supported. So you need to break large table rows (consisting in several text lines) manually in several table rows. In your original example, e.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetTblrTemplate{middlehead, lasthead, foot, caption}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
{
    hlines,
    vlines,
    columns={halign=c, valign=m, co=1},
}
    Some column & Other column \\
    \lipsum[1] \\ % Split of the one \lipsum …
    \lipsum[2] \\ % … with several paragraphs …
    \lipsum[3] \\ % … inside one single table row …
    \lipsum[4] \\ % … into six table rows, …
    \lipsum[5] \\ % … each with a single lipsum paragraph.
    \lipsum[6]
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}


BTW: I would recommend to avoid vertical rules (vlines) in tables and reduce the number of horizontal lines (hlines) to a minimum.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetTblrTemplate{middlehead, lasthead, foot, caption}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
{
    columns={halign=c, valign=m, co=1},
    rowhead=1,
}
  \toprule
  Some column & Other column \\
  \midrule
    \lipsum[1] \\ % Split of the one \lipsum …
    \lipsum[2] \\ % … with several paragraphs …
    \lipsum[3] \\ % … inside one single table row …
    \lipsum[4] \\ % … into six table rows, …
    \lipsum[5] \\ % … each with a single lipsum paragraph.
    \lipsum[6] \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}


Or for your (unfortunately after I've already answered the question) changed example:
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetTblrTemplate{firstead, middlehead, lasthead, foot, caption}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabs}
{
    columns={halign=c, valign=t, co=1},
    rowhead=1,
}
\toprule
Some column & Long text column & Some column \\
\midrule
simple text & \lipsum[1] & simple text \\ % Split of the one \lipsum …
& \lipsum[2] & \\ % … with several paragraphs …
& \lipsum[3] & \\ % … inside one single table row …
& \lipsum[4] & \\ % … into six table rows, …
& \lipsum[5] & \\ % … each with a single lipsum paragraph.
& \lipsum[6] & \\
\midrule
simple text & \lipsum[1] & simple text \\ % Split of the one \lipsum …
& \lipsum[2] & \\ % … with several paragraphs …
& \lipsum[3] & \\ % … inside one single table row …
& \lipsum[4] & \\ % … into six table rows, …
& \lipsum[5] & \\ % … each with a single lipsum paragraph.
& \lipsum[6] & \\
\midrule
simple text & \lipsum[1] & simple text \\ % Split of the one \lipsum …
& \lipsum[2] & \\ % … with several paragraphs …
& \lipsum[3] & \\ % … inside one single table row …
& \lipsum[4] & \\ % … into six table rows, …
& \lipsum[5] & \\ % … each with a single lipsum paragraph.
& \lipsum[6] & \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabs}

\end{document}

See the booktabs examples and the documentation of options like rowhead and rowfoot in the tabularray manual for more information.
And something like this also works, for table rows with very long paragraphs. By adding invisible paragraphs, e.g., splitting a \blindtext[4] of a table like:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabs}
  [
        caption={A long example},
  ]
  {
    colspec={cXc},
    rowhead=1,
  }
\toprule
Some column & Long text column & Some column \\
\midrule
simple text & \blindtext & simple text \\
\midrule
simple text & \blindtext[4] & simple text \\ % THIS DOES NOT WORK!
simple text & \blindtext & simple text \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabs}

\end{document}

into
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabs}
  [
        caption={A long example},
  ]
  {
    colspec={cXc},
    rowhead=1,
  }
\toprule
Some column & Long text column & Some column \\
\midrule
simple text & \blindtext & simple text \\
\midrule
simple text & \parfillskip=0pt \blindtext & simple text \\ % Split of the one
            & \parfillskip=0pt \blindtext[2] & \\ % \blindtext[4] into multiple
            & \blindtext & \\ % table rows to allow page breaks
simple text & \blindtext & simple text \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabs}

\end{document}


The \parfillskip=0pt is used here to “hide” the end of the paragraph. It is only needed in columns with justified text. In centered or left aligned or right aligned columns with real text, you just need to find a suitable inter-word space to break the row.
Sometimes also using a list instead of a table or using package parallel or multicol could be an options, but this depends on your table.

There is a problem with this solution: it inserts newlines between cells, I would like to don't have it.

@Intolighter I don't know, what you mean with "newlines". The \\ are not newlines, but table row separators. There are only paragraphs similar to the paragraphs you would have already with a single \lipsum. But if you don't want all the horizontal lines, just don't use option hlines, but, e.g., command \hline or the corresponding booktabs specifiers.

Paragraph newlines.

@Intolighter Sorry, for me it is absolutely unclear what you mean. Paragraphs always start a new line and in my example I explicitly start new table rows at the same places \lipsum would start a new paragraph and therefore a new line. So there are not more paragraphs or newlines than without splitting the one table row manually into six table rows. If you have a problem in splitting your table row into several table rows, you would need to ask a follow-up question that shows this problem.

I don't need several paragraphs.

@Intolighter The \lipsum in your example produces several paragraphs. And I've shown, how to split them into several table rows to allow page breaks, because page breaks are only supported between table rows. So if the shown example does not really show your problem, please ask a follow-up question with a example that shows your problem. I can only answer to the problem that has been shown. And this is what I've done.

My actual text doesn't contain paragraphs.

@Intolighter As I told several times: You are using \lipsum in your example and \lipsum contains several paragraphs. I've split the single \lipsum into \lipsum[1],\lipsum[2], …, \lipsum[6] in my answer. If you real text does not have several paragraphs, your example is bad and you should ask a follow-up question instead of changing the example in this question again. I'm telling you the same things again and again in my comments. Sorry, but if you do not understand this, it does not make sense to discuss any longer.

This is a test example, as I said my actual text which I typed in cell, which is needed to occupy several pages, contain single paragraph.

@Intolighter I've told you again and again. If you have a problem with breaking your table rows into multiple table rows, you must show your table rows. Otherwise I do not understand, why you cannot split your text suitable. Usually you just need to search for a suitable inter word space and split the text there into a new table row. I even have shown how to hide the generated paragraph in case of using justified text. So sorry, if you need more help, ask a follow-up question and show your real problem.

Didn't see you additions. Thank you!
